# Execution order of consecutive if statements in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a couple of if statements for validation purpose.

The problem now is that the order of validating is not as what I expected.

For example, I want to check if the name field if empty, and if it is empty,  check if it is between 2 and 30 characters. But when I test it, if I leave the name filed blank, it gives me the error "Name must be between 2 and 30 characters" first. It seems it jumped over the first if statement.

So, why this is the case? Why it doesn't execute in order

```
  if (Validator.isEmpty(data.name)) {
    errors.name = "Name field is required";
  }

if (!Validator.isLength(data.name, { min: 2, max: 30 })) {
    errors.name = "Name must be between 2 and 30 characters";
  }



 if (Validator.isEmpty(data.email)) {
    errors.email = "Email field is required";
  }

  if (!Validator.isEmail(data.email)) {
    errors.email = "Email is invalid";
  }
```

Comment: It did not "jump over", the later `if` statements overwrite the same value if multiple conditions are true. You need to use `else if` instead of `if` for the consecutive conditions.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It does execute in order, but then your second `if` is simply overwriting the message from the first if. You need to add code to end processing if the first if is true, or use `else if`for the second.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the 2 snippets, and look at the difference. If you just use `if (true)`, every single one will execute. To make only one execute, use `if else ()`.

```js
if (true) {
  console.log("First statement is true!");
}
if (true) {
  console.log("Second statement is true!");
}
if (true) {
  console.log("Third statement is true!");
}
```

```js
if (true) {
  console.log("First statement is true!");
}
else if (true) {
  console.log("Second statement is true!");
}
else if (true) {
  console.log("Third statement is true!");
}
```

**In your case, it both executed, but since the second one executed after the first one, `errors.name` had the value from the second if but not the first.**